# WPF with Dynamic module loading using prism

Tags: wpf, silverlight, prism

This is about WPF project with Dynamic module loading and navigation using prism. I am trying to figure out - how the WPF project loads shell module so that all related files such as Bootstrapper, catalog, etc. are initialized to register the modules (WPF projects) through catalog. This is required so we can use prism module loader.

More details below -

We are migrating a Silverlight project to a WPF project.

Silverlight Solution has following projects

- MyProject.Web (aspx) with default.aspx which is initializing shell module ("I believe") by following code
  `<param name="source" value="ClientBin/ShellModule.xap" />`
- ShellModule Silverlight project with catalog.xaml which registers all Modularity:ModuleInfo and Bootstrapper.cs inheriting UnityBootstrapper which returns IModuleCatalog
- Other Silverlight Module projects

I am trying to figure out how would WPF project achieve it without the MyProject.Web project and without a default.aspx

My very odd random guess - from App.xaml of Root project somehow?

WPF - https://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/wpf/legacy/Modules.html

Silverlight - https://www.wintellect.com/dynamic-module-loading-with-silverlight-navigation-using-prism/

Comment: Create a new WPF application, install the [Prism.Unity](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.Unity/) NuGet package and modify the `App.xaml.cs` class to inherit from `Prism.Unity.PrismApplication`. You can then take a look at [this](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf/tree/master/07-Modules%20-%20Code) example to see how to load modules dynamically.

Comment: My questions is different than how to do it since it involves code re-usability during migration.